# Error: Cannot find module 'xxx' repeats over and over?

Tags: node.js, express, npm

Trying out a tutorial using express.js to simple web server.
Problem: When I run the js, I keep getting the same error over and over saying module "x" then module "y" then module "z" is missing.
The dependent modules don't seem to get loaded.

What do I need to do to get all the dependencies in my js to be loaded automatically? (Or is this normal node.js behavior?)

Here's what I do:

1. cd to app folder
2. npm init  // package.json created
3. npm install express  // node_modules dir created. express inside.
4. node 03y.js
5. Errors like this:

> Error: Cannot find module 'body-parser'
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)

6. So I do: npm install body-parser
7. Run again: eg: Error: Cannot find module 'whatever' etc....

Am I missing a vital step?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your `require()` line...

Answer (score 0):

I guessing the tutorial is from an older version of Express. It used to come bundled with body-parser and a bunch of other middleware, now it doesn't. You can either power through it by running npm install for each module it errors out on, or find an up to date tutorial.  I'd recommend the latter, as going from 3 to 4 is not going to be easy if you're just learning.

Also, word to the wise, always add the --save flag to npm install, that'll make sure your package.json is correct on dependencies, which aids in deployment later.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should edit the file `package.json` before run the command `npm install`.

In the file `package.json`,you should add one subnode `"dependencies"`,which includes modules all you need on the project

It's  part of `package.json` of one project you can refer to:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "babel-core": "6.13.2",
        "babel-polyfill": "6.13.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015-node6": "0.3.0",
        "babel-preset-stage-3": "6.5.0",
        "sequelize": "3.24.1",
        "mysql": "2.11.1",
        "koa": "2.0.0",
        "koa-bodyparser": "3.2.0",
        "koa-router": "7.0.0",
        "koa-session2": "1.0.8",
        "nunjucks": "2.4.2",
        "mime": "1.3.4",
        "mz": "2.4.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You everyone. I will print and study replies. BTW version is express@4.14.0 node_modules\express

Than U again from newbie.... going step by slow step.